# $\frac{3^n - 5 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2}}{6^{n+1}} = -\frac{5}{27}$

Tags: exponential-function

$$\frac{3^n - 5 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2}}{6^{n+1}} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

I currently don't have any idea about where to start. Can you take a look?

My attempt:

$$\frac{3^n - 5 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n}\cdot 3}{6^{n+1}} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

$$\frac{3^n  (-5 \cdot  + 3^{-2})}{6^{n+1}} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

Regards,

Comment: Start with $\,3^n - 5 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2}=3^{n-2}(3^2 - 5 \cdot 3 + 1)\,$ and go from there.

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $n$ or to prove this is an identity?

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm trying to get $n$.

Comment: @dxiv What have you done there and got nothing.

Comment: @Displayed I pulled a factor of $3^{n-2}$ out of the numerator, which will cancel out with *some part* of the denominator after you write that one as $\,2^{n+1} \cdot 3^{n+1}\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{3^n - 5 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2}}{6^{n+1}} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

$$\frac{3^n (1- \frac{5}3 + \frac19)}{6^{n}\cdot 6} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

$$\left(\frac12\right)^n\frac{ (1- \frac{5}3 + \frac19)}{ 6} = -\frac{5}{27}$$

Try to isolate $\left(\frac12\right)^n$ and then take logarithm to complete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution $K = 3^{n-2}$ and exponent/power rules.